# Combining fragments of data in a generator pipeline

Tags: python, generator

Edit: it seems flow based (or reactive) programming approach would help here; there are some libraries in python that try that.

I tried to follow the generator pipeline style (see [David Beazley's famous presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/)) for finding duplicate files (similar to answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748675/finding-duplicate-files-and-removing-them)). It seems pretty straightforward with MapReduce, so I thought it should also be possible to produce a clean, simple code with a generator pipeline. I tried both lambdas and named functions, but couldn't find how.

My code is especially ugly in `get_digest` where it's detecting that the `digest` has been completed for a particular file. Also annoying is the boilerplate code I use to propagate the source `filepath` through the pipeline.

Of course, I can just rewrite everything with nested loops, but I thought maybe I'm missing an obvious approach? Perhaps I should try to invert the data flow direction by using coroutines? Or use some `itertools`-style techniques to create a non-tree shaped data flow?

```
# python 3.5 but nothing important lost if I port it to python 2.7
import os
import glob
import collections
import hashlib
import functools

BUFFER_SIZE = 2 ** 20

def get_files(filepaths):
    for filepath in filepaths:
        yield open(filepath, mode='rb'), filepath

def read_files(files):
    for file, filepath in files:
        for data in iter(functools.partial(file.read, BUFFER_SIZE), b''):
            yield data, filepath

def get_digests(data_iter):
    current_filepath = None
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha256()
    for data, filepath in data_iter:
        if filepath != current_filepath:
            if current_filepath is not None:
                yield hash_obj.digest(), current_filepath
            current_filepath = filepath
        hash_obj.update(data)
    yield hash_obj.digest(), current_filepath

def find_duplicates(root_folder):
    '''
    Args:
    root_folder: folder to start searching from
    Returns:
    a list of lists of paths that correspond to duplicate files
    '''

    # combine generators into a pipeline
    paths = glob.iglob(os.path.join(root_folder, '**'), recursive=True)
    filepaths = filter(os.path.isfile, paths)
    files = get_files(filepaths)
    data_iter = read_files(files)
    digests = get_digests(data_iter)

    # collect data into a dictionary, then list
    # I feel this part is ok
    duplicates = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for digest, filepath in digests:
        duplicates[digest].append(filepath)
    return [v for v in duplicates.values() if len(v) >=2]

# print duplicate files found in the current folder or below
duplicates = find_duplicates('.')
for group in duplicates:
    print('the following files are duplicates:')
    for filename in group:
        print(filename)
    print('\n')
```

Update:

Here's the slightly modified code from @ferada answer (who fixed a bug in my code and made my code much cleaner). Per @ferada suggestion, I made `get_digest` just deal with digest calculation, and factored out the grouping code.

```
import pprint, os, glob, collections, hashlib, functools, itertools, sys, operator

BUFFER_SIZE = 2 ** 20

def read_files(filepaths):
    for filepath in filepaths:
        with open(filepath, mode='rb') as file:
            for data in iter(functools.partial(file.read, BUFFER_SIZE), b''):
                yield data, filepath

def get_digest(hash_obj, iterator):
    for data in iterator:
        hash_obj.update(data)
    return hash_obj.digest()

def get_digests(data_iter):
    for filepath, group in itertools.groupby(data_iter, key=lambda x: x[1]):
        yield get_digest(hashlib.sha256(), map(operator.itemgetter(0), group)), filepath

def scantree(path):
    """Recursively yield DirEntry objects for given directory.
    From https://stackoverflow.com/a/33135143/336527
    """
    with os.scandir(path) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
                yield from scantree(entry.path)  # see below for Python 2.x
            else:
                yield entry

def find_files(root_folder):
    '''Yields full paths of all files starting with root_folder, recursively'''
    for entry in scantree(root_folder):
        if entry.is_file():
            yield entry.path

def find_duplicates(root_folder):
    '''
    Args:
    root_folder: folder to start searching from
    Yields:
    Tuples of paths that correspond to duplicate files
    '''
    filepaths = find_files(root_folder)
    data_iter = read_files(filepaths)
    digests = get_digests(data_iter)

    for _, group in itertools.groupby(digests, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        _, filepaths = zip(*group)
        if len(filepaths) >= 2:
            yield filepaths

def main():
    folder = sys.argv[1]
    for dup in find_duplicates(folder):
        pprint.pprint(dup)
```

The passing around of `filepath` as a second argument in yield remains an annoyance to be fixed.

Comment: get_files should be get_file_names and just return filenames. yield open() smells for me.

Comment: Besides, why just hash 2 ** 20 bytes of a file?

Comment: @MKesper I'm pretending the files are too big to fit in memory. If you want to be more realistic, replace `2 ** 20` with `2 ** 30` or something.

Comment: @MKesper and yes, I also don't like `yield open()` now, because it's much easier to close the file in the same loop than somewhere further down in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- That has been already mentioned, but for completeness sake, always
  take care to clean up resources, including open file handles.  Based
  on that I'd suggest merging `get_files` into `read_files`.
- Globbing and then filtering for files can be replaced with a
  [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir)
  call, which might be a bit more efficient because the file information
  isn't being fetched twice, see the link for details on that.  N.b. I'm
  not using a `with` here because it was only added in Python 3.6 - that
  is, please **do** use a `with` like shown in the docs.
- I'd also suggest adding docstrings to the other functions - it's not
  immediately obvious what they do and more importantly what the return
  values are going to be.
- `list(get_digests([]))` gives me a non-empty list.  I'd say that's not
  the best interface there.
- The duplicate-detection part of `find_duplicates` could also be
  generic given how the grouping works by a key, e.g. using
  [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).
- `get_digests` is buggy, a new digest object needs to be used for each
  file.

I find this disentangled structure harder to understand than if it was a
single function that produced the digests.

That said, since you explicitely want to use this kind of pipeline,
perhaps consider having a (reusable) grouping step separate from
`get_digests` and then produce digests using a simpler function that
doesn't have *both* grouping and hashing in it.

---

FWIW looks like this now:

```python
# python 3.5 but nothing important lost if I port it to python 2.7
import os
import glob
import collections
import hashlib
import functools
import itertools


BUFFER_SIZE = 2 ** 20


def read_files(filepaths):
    for filepath in filepaths:
        with open(filepath, mode='rb') as file:
            for data in iter(functools.partial(file.read, BUFFER_SIZE), b''):
                yield data, filepath


def get_digests(data_iter):
    for filepath, group in itertools.groupby(data_iter, lambda x: x[1]):
        hash_obj = hashlib.sha256()
        for data, _ in group:
            hash_obj.update(data)
        yield hash_obj.digest(), filepath


def find_files(root_folder):
    for entry in os.scandir(root_folder):
        if entry.is_file():
            yield entry.name


def find_duplicates(root_folder):
    '''
    Args:
    root_folder: folder to start searching from
    Returns:
    a list of lists of paths that correspond to duplicate files
    '''

    # combine generators into a pipeline
    digests = get_digests(read_files(find_files(root_folder)))

    for digest, group in itertools.groupby(digests, lambda x: x[0]):
        filepaths = list(group)
        if len(filepaths) >= 2:
            yield filepaths


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # print duplicate files found in the current folder or below
    for group in find_duplicates('.'):
        print('the following files are duplicates:')
        for filename in group:
            print(filename)
        print('\n')
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't think of using `groupby`, it works so well in both cases. There are a couple of changes needed (`yield entry.name` --> `yield entry.path`, adding recursive traversal, removing the hash from the final output), but they are straightforward. I'll include the final code in the edit to my question. But as for my original question, I guess there's no simple way to avoid carrying around `filepath` in each generator of the pipeline?

Comment: Right good catch, was a bit hasty when answering it seems -.- Well you're using the `filepath` to group on, I don't think you can get rid of it?

Comment: I meant, is there any way to get access to `filepath` in a more elegant way than manually adding it to the `yield` of every step of the pipeline? And I guess the answer with simple python generators is no -- but perhaps some libraries that deal with data flow programming might provide access to the results of earlier steps of the pipeline in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not closing files.

Comment: No I'm not. I rely on the garbage collector to do it: when `find_duplicates` returns, all the file objects become unreachable and will be (eventually) closed when they are garbage collected. To explicitly close them would seem to require even more ugly coding?

Comment: This answer could be useful if you pointed out the locations and file handles that are not closed properly.

Comment: Relying on the garbage collector to close files is [expecting interpreter-dependent behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7396043/1157100). I would still consider it to be a leak, and in any case, poor design.